# Angularjs: How does the Angular hide and show elements?where should I modify the elements?

Tags: angularjs, hide

I'd like to hide the angular app until the view is rendered.
I propable have to hide it using `style="display:none":`

```
 <div id="app-content" style="display:none">
      <!-- Angular app HTML code -->
 </div>
```

I have tried this, it won't work, because Angular does not modify the style.display value.

```
<div id="app-content" style="display:none" ng-show="1">
```

How does Angular hide elements, where should I modify the style.display, or is there a better solution?

Comment: you mean to say load view from route or by making ajax?

Comment: if any methods mentioned above is not helping, then checkout
https://stackoverflow.com/a/44942863/5902146

Comment: ng-cloak is the answer. we can also use ng-show or ng-hide in combination with ng-cloak. this link has details about ng-cloak  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

Answer (score 4):

### How does Angular show and hide elements?

*This is depends on  `Boolean` (`true` or `false`) value*

---

### **ng-show** :

- `ng-show="true"` is same as `style="display:block"`
- `ng-show="false"` is same as `style="display:none"`

---

### **ng-hide** :

This is same as ng-show by depends on `true` or `false`  value

- `ng-hide="true"` is same as `style="display:none"`
- `ng-hide="false"` is same as `style="display:block"`

if you use `ng-show` or `ng-hide`, then you don't need call the `display` properties in your `style`

---

### Where should I modify the style.display, or is there a better solution?

You don't need `style.display` if you using `angular.js`. just try with `ng-show` and `ng-hide`.

if you use `ng-show` or `hide`, then you can do the changes in your controller.

like something below

```
<div  ng-show="modelName">......
```

you need to modify the `modelName` in your controller.

```
function controllername($scope)
{
$scope.modelName="true"// or false
}
```

---

Comment: Thank you, but I think I got misunderstood.
If I load a page which angular is using, it might take a few seconds until the angular.js is loaded OR the angular.js can't be loaded.

The user will see a page with {{ }}'s and elements which should be hidden, are visible, until Angular has rendered the view. An ng-hide/ng-show won't work before the loading and rendering is completed.

Comment: @Artisan72, use ng-bind instead of `{{}}` if you don't want users see it before angular render or check [ng-cloak](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak)

Answer (score 1):

Try it.

```
<div id="app-content" ng-show="false">
```

**or**

```
<div id="app-content" ng-hide="true">
```

You don't have need to use `display:none` with angularjs because it provides `ng-hide` and `ng-show` directives to do this kind of lots of things.

for more information visit this link [Angularjs doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow)

Answer (score 0):

You also could use a html attribute directive called `ng-cloak` and hide elements that have that particular html attribute. `ng-cloak` removes itselfs at the end of the digest cicle - also after the curly braces were removed. So you do not have to use the ng-bind syntax.

In HTML/CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
    [ng-cloak] {
       display:none;
    }
</style>
```

Then use it like `required` attribute

```
<div ng-hide="someVar" ng-cloak="">{{someOtherPerhaps}}</div>
```