# AngularJS: ng-show vs display:none

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, ng-show

I had a use case whereby I have to keep an HTML element hidden by default using CSS as follows:

HTML:

```
<div class="item">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.item {
    display: none;
}
```

But, I need to toggle the element's visibility using ng-show after the page has loaded as follows:

```
<div class="item" ng-show="show_element">
</div>
```

But, even if `$scope.show_element` is set to true, the element doesn't become visible, that is, the css property is overriding AngularJS' ng-show. Is there any way to give ng-show more priority?

Also, you may think I can keep `$scope.show_element` as false initially to hide it. But in that case, I get a very short glimpse of the element when the page is loading which is not good from the UX point of view.

Comment: Use ng-class instead and apply class that will have display: block in certain cases

Comment: @Kailas please read the last para of the question.

Comment: why not go for ng-if instead?

Comment: let me try that, the thing is I am getting a very brief glimpse of the element with ngshow set to false. Let me see if thats also the case with ng-if.

Comment: nah, still facing the same problem. The element is shown initially for probably half a second and only then does the ng-if kick in.

Comment: try setting the default visiblity of the element as hidden  and use ng-if it will work fine.

Comment: sorry, @Kailas not working.

Comment: @maurycy, thanks it worked!

Comment: Or you can use old good ng-cloak if it takes that long to bootstrap your app

Comment: well, the ng-class solution worked thanks a lot :)

Comment: I'll post it as an answer in that case :)

Comment: Yes that would be a good idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to make it work in your case would be using `ng-class` where in case when element should be visible you can apply class with correct display property i.e. `display: block` and if you suffer from slow bootstrap you can use `ng-cloak` check documentation here https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak

Comment: `ng-cloak` sounds like the op's root issue. However be aware angular needs to have loaded on the page for it to take effect. Angular doesn't have to be bootstrapped but it does need to be loaded. Otherwise you will need to target the attribute with css yourself if you have a slow loading page for what ever reason.

Answer (score 5):

**Another simple alternative**

```
style="{{show_element?'display:block !important':'display:none !important'}}"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are just trying to hide the item so that you don't get a flash on-load, then instead of using the `.item` class set to `display:none`, you could simply set a class of `.ng-hide` to the element with `ng-show` on.

The AngularJS directive `ng-show` works by adding or removing a class of `.ng-hide` to the DOM element. The `.ng-hide` class applies the rule `display: none !important;`

```
<div class="ng-hide" ng-show="showElement">...</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

I would simply change the class. Ng-shows function is to simply add or remove the ng-hide class, which only propertie is a "display: none !important;". It is not ment to change the css of the classes.

What you could simply do is something like this:

```
<div class="{{element_class}} item">
</div>
```

And set the **element_class** to your class with **display:block;**

Working example:
http://codepen.io/GriessbreiLP/pen/EVXQjK

Hope this might help you.

Edit: 
Nah, too slow, already mentioned two times.